# Detecting when home is pressed in a child Activity from Parent Acitvity

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a list View  of file names ( of files stored in the sdcard)  in Activity A . When an item in the listView is clicked , an ACTION_VIEW intent is fired . It brings up a list of Apps with which the user can open the file . When a user chooses one of them  , it opens the file in Activity B . IF the user presses the HOME button while viewing the file , I want to delete the file which is stored in the SDCard. How can I do so ?

I obviously cannot use the OnPause / OnStop of the parent activity to delete the file and I cannot access the onPause / onStop of an Activity invoked through an intent . Since it is a home press , I cannot call onActivityResult on Activity A from Activity B.

Is there anyway of detecting the home button press in an  Activity called through an intent ? Or is there an alternate way of achieving the required result ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I do't think you can respond to home key presses. This is to prevent applications from hijacking it. See [KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_HOME) - according to the documentation, "Key code constant: Home key. This key is handled by the framework and is never delivered to applications."

Comment: Yes , I am aware of that . I was thinking of using onPause/ onStop maybe .